# Confusion about the sorting function

Tags: sorting

The following one-dimensional array can be sorted well:

```
Sort[{Infinity, 10, 2, 1, -4}, #1 < #2 &]
```

But the following two-dimensional array cannot sort the `Infinity` symbols:

```
Sort[{{1, 9, 7, 2}, {0, 2, -(9/2), 2}, {0, -(11/2), -(11/2), -t}, {s, 
    10, 9, 7}, 
       {1, 2, 4, 3}} /. {0 -> Infinity}, #1[[1]] <= #2[[1]] & ]
```

However, the following method also sorts the elements in the second column without permission:

```
SortBy[{{1, 9, 7, 2}, {0, 2, -(9/2), 
    2}, {0, -(11/2), -(11/2), -t}, {s, 10, 9, 7}, 
       {1, 2, 4, 3}} /. {0 -> Infinity}, First]
```

[image]

I want to know the reasons for these problems and how to sort the two-dimensional array $\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 9 & 7 & 2 \\
\infty  & 2 & -\frac{9}{2} & 2 \\
\infty & -\frac{11}{2} & -\frac{11}{2} & -t \\
5 & 10 & 9 & 7 \\
1 & 2 & 4 & 3
\end{array}\right)$ only by the first column of elements.

Comment: Am I missing something here?
`SortBy[...,{First}]`...

Comment: @ciao Thank you very much for solving the second problem, but why can't the following code sort the matrix correctly :`Sort[{{1, 9, 7, 2}, {0, 2, -(9/2), 2}, {0, -(11/2), -(11/2), -t}, {s, 
    10, 9, 7}, 
       {1, 2, 4, 3}} /. {0 -> Infinity}, #1[[1]] <= #2[[1]] & ]`.

Comment: look at the result of say `1<=x`... you should be able to figure it out then.
Hint: use `OrderedQ[{#1[[1]], #2[[1]]}] &` as your function if you must insist on `Sort` vs `SortBy`

Comment: @ciao Thank you very much.